# Attachment image single page

Tags: posts, single, images

How do I make a single post page for a single attachment image below and link to it?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="body">
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<div class="page_title">
<h2><?php single_cat_title(); ?></h2>
</div>
<div class="photos">
<ul class="lb-album">
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $images = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'za_plupload');  ?>
<?php   
$images = implode( ',' , $images );
$images = $wpdb->get_col( "
SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}
WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
AND ID in ({$images})
ORDER BY menu_order ASC
" );
?>
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php foreach ($images as $att) {
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($att, 'full');
$src = $src[0]; 
$image_path =  thumbGen($src,330,0,"crop=1&halign=center&valign=center&return=1");
$image_all = get_bloginfo('url').$image_path;
$my_image = array_values(getimagesize($image_all));
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = $my_image;
?>
<li class="box image_holder" style="height:<?php echo $height; ?>px!important;"><a href="<?php echo $image_path2; ?>" style="height:<?php echo $height; ?>px!important;"><img src="<?php echo $image_path; ?>" alt="" width="330"  height="<?php echo $height; ?>" class="image" /></a></li>
<?php $i++; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif;?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to [the Template Hierarchy for attachment post types](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Attachment_display):

- `$mimetype.php
- `$attachment.php`
- `single-attachment.php`
- `single.php`
- `index.php`

So for an image attachment, name your template file `image.php`.

Then, to link to the single post view for an attachment, you would link to it like any other post: `get_the_permalink( $postid )`.